# Bootstrap 3 scrollspy to change class of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can I use the scrollspy to change the class of a div. I can rewrite the code to do it but if there is a way to tweak scrollspy to do it I obviously would prefer going that route.

```
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top at-top" role="navigation">
```

changes to

```
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top not-at-top" role="navigation">
```

When the user scrolls past

```
<section class="how-it-works" id="how-it-works">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes simple Jquery can help

```
$('#how-it-works').scroll(function() {
    if($('#how-it-works').offset().top + $('#how-it-works').height() <   $(this).offset().top) {
    $('#navbar').removeClass('at-top').addClass('not-at-top');    
} else {
    $('#navbar').addClass('at-top').removeClass('not-at-top');
}
});
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. Made a few tweaks but works like a charm. Used: `$(window).scroll(function()` and `$(document).scrollTop()` but same principle....